# Can I purchase an App from the Mac App Store for multiple users?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, volume-purchase-program

How do I make a bulk purchase of an app on the Mac App Store? I know there are 2 options for bulk purchasing: Apple Business Manager Account and Apple School Manager Account but what if I do not have these accounts.

Is there a way?

Comment: You can use iCloud family to share 1 purchase with 6 people added to the family.

Comment: I don't want to share my iCloud with them. They aren't family either.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You are not sharing your iCloud with them. What you are doing is you can purchase an app or Apple Service and share it with up to 6 people added to the iCloud family plan. How many users do you have to purchase it for?

Comment: Around 10-20. Also, I do not want to share one app but buy multiple licenses.

Comment: Have you looked at an MDM solution? Which software are you looking at?

Comment: Is there a gift feature on the Mac App Store? If there is, I can use it for my use case.

Comment: For MDM, I think I would need a Business Account. Am I right?

Comment: Even for MDM you need to have ABM or ASM to get the licenses.  Regarding gifting an app, I don't think it's possible in the MAS.

Comment: The solution I am thinking to use is the Gift option in iTunes. I will purchase 10 gift cards close to the app price that I wanted to buy and then ask my users to redeem it on the Mac App Store.

I couldn't find a gift option on the Mac App Store but there is one on the iTunes and it can be redeemed on the Mac App Store as per this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7384133

Pl, correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want or have [ABM or ASM](https://developer.apple.com/support/volume-purchase-and-custom-apps/) then the only way to make a bulk purchase is to work out something with the app developer.

This kind of purchase would be outside the Mac App Store and could involve some difficulty with installation and support.

Outside of these methods, there no supported (by Apple or, probably, the developer) to purchase multiple licenses or software copies.